# 403 forbidden error in artica-postfix

Tags: apache-2.2, postfix, email-server, centos5

I have a CentOS 5.5 server. I have configured the latest version of artica-postfix on this server.  All was going well but after logging with the URL https://108.163.173.178:9000 I got the error:-`403 - Forbidden`.

I know its an Apache error, so can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Post the relevant parts of the Apache config and the log entries (Error log!) generated when you try to open that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 can have a couple of reasons:

1. You are trying to access a directory which is simply "forbidden" for the webserver user. It is not enough to give adequate permissions to the directory itself, but also the leading path.
2. You are missing the `<Directory>` directive and/or
3. You haven't defined a `DirectoryIndex` and the Apache is adviced to not serve `Indexes` within the `Options` part of its configuration (per directory)

The list is not even complete, but those are the ones I had most often, when asked for help. As mentioned in the comment, we need more informations from your side to be remotely able to help.

Check the logfiles as well to get those neccessary informations.